# Loop data fetched from val()

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to get some data from a hidden  element and loop through it and have it in an array.

The element looks like this:

```
<input class="test" type="hidden" name="fwrls" value='[{"comment":"test1","policy":"deny","proto":"any"},{"comment":"test2","policy":"allow","proto":"any""}]'>
```

Now when I grab this with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var data = $(".test").val();
  console.log(data);
  //test loop
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i]);
  } 
});
```

But it loops through every character instead of each {} in [].

What am I missing?

JS Bin for reference: https://jsbin.com/madaquyepa/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you retrieve the input element's value, it is a string (a JSON actually). So, you will need to pass it through `JSON.parse()` first.

Note: there is an extraneous `"` near the very end of the string, which will cause an error if you try to parse it. Remember to fix it first.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = JSON.parse($(".test").val());
  console.log(data);

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="test" type="hidden" name="fwrls" value='[{"comment":"test1","policy":"deny","proto":"any"},{"comment":"test2","policy":"allow","proto":"any"}]'>
```

For an ES6 version that doesn't even use jQuery:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('.test').value);
console.log(data);

for (let datum of data) {
  console.log(datum);
}
```

```html
<input class="test" type="hidden" name="fwrls" value='[{"comment":"test1","policy":"deny","proto":"any"},{"comment":"test2","policy":"allow","proto":"any"}]'>
```